# Bigquery BQ Alerts for Slots and Query concurrency

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to establish email alerts at a project level to send email alerts for when a certain number of query/job concurrency is reached e.g. 5 concurrent queries. We have a flat-rate pricing model.

I want to do a similar email notification when total slot Usage exceeds a certain threshold as well e.g. slot usage reaching 1000 slots

As a next step I would like to throttle new incoming queries based on the above mentioned thresholds. Meaning if there are already for example 5 queries actively running the 6th one will be put on hold until one of the 5 running earlier have completed.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may create an [Alert Policy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring-dashboard#create-alert) in which you can set your desired **metric type** (eg. *slots*) and then configure your desired threshold similar to below.
[image]
[image]

In creating an **Alert Policy** you may also configure the notification channel to **email notification** which is also included on the same [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring-dashboard#expandable-1).

For the available metric types for *SLOTS* in BigQuery, you may refer to this  [Google Cloud Metrics for BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-bigquery) documentation.

For your next step, you may code (python, node.js, etc) using **BigQuery API** to count queries actively running (through JOB ID) and when the count hits 5, you may print "query queue is full" and then wait for the total JOBS to hit below 5 before running the next query. You may refer to this [BigQuery Managing Jobs API Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-jobs).